# + / - keys on non-US keyboards

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, keyboard-layout

Many shortcuts require to use the <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> keys.

Example :

- zoom or dezoom with Chrome : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd>.
- some websites (such as this [one](https://anvaka.github.io/panzoom/demo/index.html)) use <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> keys to do certain actions

(I have a laptop with no mousewheel / no numpad).

**Problem: with a FR keyboard (non-US):**

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> works but <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd> **doesn't work in Chrome**
- the website I mentioned **doesn't recognize <kbd>-</kbd>**

**Question: is there a workaround to make <kbd>-</kbd> recognized as it should be?** Maybe using AutoHotkey?

Note: the `-` is on the `6 - |` key below <kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: What about ctrl + shift + 6?

Comment: @Mokubai Doesn't work. Ctrl + 6 doesn't work either. Sidenote: on a FR keyboard, "Shift + 6" gives `6` and the "6" key alone gives `-`... Said in another way: digits are obtained with Shift (this is different to US keyboard!)

Comment: I believe this issue related to laptops only. I do not have any issues with full-sized non-US (RU) keyboard.

Comment: Buy an external numpad only keyboard

Comment: As a solution you could try to remap keys https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/

Comment: I'd use **AutoHotkey** to [remap](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm) keys or key combinations to other ones. **Advantage:** you can  [make a remapping context-sensitive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#remarks), that is you can assign a key(-combination) to do different actions in different programs, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remap a key combo with Autohotkey, like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe appname.exe

^SC00C::
    send ^{-}
return
```

Where `appname` is name of your executable so this key combo works only within this app.

Edit: the above code does not work in Chrome for some reason (although works in Firefox and other software, strange).

Below is working code, works for me in Chrome, Win 10. It rebinds both `-` and `Ctrl` `-`.
It looks a bit strange but works well.

**NOTE:  for correct functionality the script must be executed only when EN layout is on. Otherwise it may substitute all hotkeys with other key values depending on current layout.**

```
^SC00C::
    send ^{SC00C}
return

SC00C:: 
    send {-}
return
```

Or you can bind it to numpad minus, which should work in Chrome and many other apps as zoom out.

```
^SC00C::
    send ^{NumpadSub}
return

SC00C:: 
    send {NumpadSub}
return
```

See [special keys documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) for tips on how to find out scancodes for different keys.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already use AutoHotkey a lot, but here I don't know which key to change with which other one. With your code `^SC00C:: send ^{SC00C}` which key do you replace with which other one? (I see `SC00C` twice, is it a typo?) Do you have FR keyboard too?

Comment: @Basj see the update with working solution and some tips.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MikhailV's answer, here is what I use on French keyboard laptop (working):

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#ifWinActive, Chrome
    ^-:: Send ^{NumpadSub}
#ifWinActive
```

(Without this, I confirm that doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-/6/|</kbd> key (on top of <kbd>T</kbd> key of French keyboard) isn't working out of the box)